# WYSIWYG editor that produces responsive HTML

Tags: html, css, html-editor, wysiwyg

Is there an embeddable WYSIWYG HTML editor that produces responsive HTML that you've had success with?

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC application using HTML5, CSS, JavaScript, Bootstrap, C#, Entity Framework, and Visual Studio. I would like to build in a feature that enables the client to design and create their own page that then becomes part of the application. This application will be viewed mostly on mobile devices, so the resulting HTML/CSS must have responsive design incorporated into it. I then will need to manipulate the HTML slightly (so I can track what links are clicked in the custom page) and save the HTML to a SQL database. I'm considering tools such as CKEditor and TinyMCE, but I can't find anything saying that they produce responsive HTML/CSS that looks good on devices of all sizes.

It would also be nice if the editor contained the ability to insert a grid system such as the Bootstrap grid system.

Is there such an embeddable WYSIWYG HTML editor that produces responsive HTML that you've had success with?

Comment: https://bootstrapstudio.io is an application-based WYSIWYG editor for bootstrap. You most likely cant embed it though.